# Date Field with N/A

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

I have a field in SharePoint that I created in InfoPath that is a date specific field. I want a person to be able to put N/A in the field also if they don't have a date. Is this possible with formatting?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think its possible.

Workaround.. Add a checkbox next to the date field. Initially disable the Field.. Enable the field if they select the checkbox.

Comment: Yeah I tried validation, action and formatting but I might just leave as is.

Answer (score 1):

Make the default date 1/1/1900 or some such.  This is a semi-common "null" value for date fields.

Comment: I found another way.

Comment: Please do share your own answer for posterity.

Comment: I hid the field from the users view because of a previously answered question in the forum. Easier to do rather than make it complicated for another user to understand.